# Testing backend code in Django

Tags: django, backend

I am writing an authentication back-end in Django to log only a few users.

It is in a folder called restrictedauthentification/ which is at the root of my Django Project. (I am written it down for a specific project.)
It has two files in it : `backend.py` and `tests.py`

In the last file, I have written down some tests for it.
But I can't run them with command `./manage.py` test because it isn't an installed app.

Any ideas how I could run them ?

Comment: Why not make it an installed app? You just need an empty models.py.

Comment: Well that would be my last hope solution, because I don't want to make my backend an app and I don't want to create a empty model.py, but I was hoping for another solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a solution that keep me from turning my backend into a module.

Somthing that I didn't understand and that could help some beginners : In python, a test cannot run itself. It need to be executed by a TestRunner.

Now, one could use the `TextTestRunner` bundled python that execute the tests and show the results on the standard output, but when testing with django, one need to do one thing before and after the test: calling the function `setup_test_environment()` and `teardown_test_environment()`.

So I just created a class that inherit from `TextTestRunner` and redefine its methode `run()` in order that it execute the two functions provided by Django.

Here it is :

```
from restrictedauthentification.tests import TestRestrictedAuthentification
from django.test.utils import setup_test_environment, teardown_test_environment
from unittest import TextTestRunner

class DeadSimpleDjangoTestRunner(TextTestRunner):
    def run(self, test):
        setup_test_environment()
        super().run(test)
        teardown_test_environment()
```